# Advantages of declaring Reference Libraries in C#?

Tags: c#

I notice in a lot of C# programs, people use to put a huge list of stuff like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
```

What is the advantage of doing stuff like this? I mean I know it lets you shorthand some functions, so instead of "System.Xml.XPath.XElement.Parse()", I can just put "XElement.Parse()". But what other advantages are there? Are there really any advantages besides the short hand?

Are there any disadvantages?

Comment: That has nothing to do with reference libraries. You're confusing assemblies with namespaces.

Comment: But "short hand" is a really big "advantage". System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.InitiatorServiceModelSecurityTokenRequirement would be a bitch to type after a while.

Comment: @JTA: Not just to type, but to support.  That's a lot of noise to cloud up the code file.  (Though, to be fair, `InitiatorServiceModelSecurityTokenRequiremen‌​t` also seems like a bit of a pain to type.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of besides making the code a lot more readable is this:

```
using Num = System.Numerics.BigInteger;
```

Giving short and custom names for specific classes in different namespaces.
Might also help avoiding confusion between classes with the same name in different namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

It's really just the "shorthand" as you mention.  The example you give:

```
System.Xml.XPath.XElement
```

demonstrates it quite nicely.  You're looking to interact with an `XElement`.  That's all.  The rest of the fully-qualified reference is just noise.  There's no reason to write it over and over throughout the code.

It's just a measure of writing cleaner, more concise, and more expressive code which focuses on the meaningful parts of the logic, as opposed to the structural scaffolding for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The idea with namespaces is to qualify a type and this provides a convenient way for doing so. An advantage of including your usings at the top of a file is the short hand and generally translates into more readable code. But disadvantages are that you may end up with conflicting namespaces if types in two namespaces clash. In which case, you can take a look at creating an alias instead.

Answer (score 0):

The using statements provide a sneak peak as to what this code is using as well as providing shorthand access to namespace members. Typically when I'm looking at a new file I'll queue up certain APIs into shorthand memory based off what is included. *(This doesn't always work when dealing with sloppy programmers.)*